# Disable aero preview for MDI Window

Tags: c++, mfc

In windows 7 the taskbar will preview all the mdi childs, any way to disable this with MFC?

Comment: Document the style flags for the child windows.  Make sure they do *not* include WS_EX_APPWINDOW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a `FALSE` parameter to the `EnableTaskbarInteraction(...)` call in the `InitInstance` method disables displaying MFC MDI child views in the Win7 Taskbar.